# Changing Universe vs Infinity:

Tags: logic, cosmology, infinity

If we accept the idea of a dynamic, changing, evolving Universe (Big Bang Theory), must Infinity remain entirely conceptual?

If the Universe is changing and evolving, this necessarily implies borders and constraints, or there is nothing which can change or evolve.

If so, there would seem to be 'no room' for any sort of Infinity in such a Universe. It seems to me that only a 'Steady State Universe' can potentially contain an Infinity.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question really belongs here. This seems more like a matter of physics/mathematics rather than philosophy. See here maybe: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64197/is-there-anything-physically-infinite

Comment: "If the Universe is changing and evolving, this necessarily implies borders and constraints, or there is nothing which can change or evolve." Why?

Comment: I am surprised that some as astute as yourself should ask this question - I believe it is elementary: Change, at the least, means moving through time from point A to point B. (or some analogous sort of movement or change of state) Therefore point A is **DISCREET**, as is point B, and there is of necessity a boundary between them.  - all change requires **boundaries**. Otherwise, we have a state of perfect entropy, in which no change can occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in your understanding

- In "steady state" universe practically (in a large enough time period) things would repeat itself, and, in this sense, nothing new happens. But this would call some kind of finiteness. Just the opposite of your inferrence.Maybe you need to justify why only a steady-state universe would allow infinities? Actually even in a steady state universe, things can still "change" as in the way i will describe below allowing infinities.
- Just assume that the way things change in an "always-changing universe" (or even in a "steady-state universe") happens to be related with decimal expansion of  Pi (3.141592...). We know that there will be no repetition in this sequence no matter how long you count (or wait). Isn't this a room for a kind of infinity in both kinds of universes? The sequence of Pi decimal digits starts with a 1 and this may (for the sake of discussion) correspond to the "big-bang" moment. Still, you miss the other end. Kind of infinity, even if one-sided? Probably.

I would say that steady-stateness seems to have nothing to do with allowing or disallowing infinities. In both cases, for instance, the space itself or its geometry, or the fabric of the matter, would allow infinities.

Comment: "things would repeat itself, and, in this sense, nothing new happens" **??** No need for repetition if we have infinity!

Comment: Exactly. However, not all infinities dismiss the need for repetition but some certainly do. Even the repetition itself , if it is there, can be infinite. The point is that to have an infinity you don't need a steady-state universe. Both repetitious and ever-changing stuff leave room for infinities. Even in a universe with boundaries, you could have infinite entities within the boundaries.

Comment: 'Even in a universe with boundaries, you could have infinite entities within the boundaries.' This is new and interesting territory to me and **perhaps** you have convinced me - at least sufficiently so for me to accept your answer. Your example of Pi in connection with this subject and the concept of repeating infinities are very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If the universe is everything that we see then according to current cosmological theories it is bounded. That is it is bounded spatially (as determined by General Relativity). It has been an open question as to whether it is unbounded in the future, current measurements indicate that it is unbounded in the future. But time unlike space we can only probe the present and memory & knowledge of the past. At every present moment what we see is a bounded, but expanding universe to the future and spatially.

But one can speculate - and plenty do - that there are other universes or all that we see is not the whole of the universe. For example the multiverse.

Where should one place the universe of mathematics? Is it in this universe. Is it elsewhere? Surely that is an infinite realm of thought.

Perhaps one can use a Turing Machine to enumerate every possible axiom system - certainly it wouldn't halt.

But why mathematics? Why not biology. The space of possible biological species is infinite too. As is all the possibilities of languages, and scripts and all the poems and essays and jokes that could be written.

Should mathematics have that high role that is traditionally awarded by it by philosophy? As a glimpse of the eternal.

Aristotle denied the possibility that humans can ever grasp a whole infinity, they can see only the potential. Since this has nothing to do with the nature of the universe - it applies whether the universe is steady-state or a big-bang. It rests upon an analysis of what infinite means. He states that the infinite is not an object or a thing. So it can't be identified with the universe.

Comment: Within the lambda-CDM model, the latest measurements from WMAP indicate a spatially infinite (i.e. unbounded) universe with very high certainty, and very likely temporally unbounded in its future as well if dark energy is as important as we believe it to be. I'd suggest revising your first paragraph.

Comment: @DavidH: Ok, but I have a few questions first. How is it possible to measure an infinite spatial extent? Surely the most they can say is that it extends to such or such a distance. My understanding of the Big Bang is that both spacetime & matter unfolded at the same time which means that spacetime must be bounded. But of course experimental results trumps empirical theories. So how exactly does the WMAP experiment indicate a *spatially* unbounded universe, I can go along with the *temporal* unboundedness in the future.

Comment: Also, you might enjoy skimming NASA's online summary of WMAP: http://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/universe/uni_shape.html

Comment: @DavidH: The exact form of the equation isn't important. I'll correct for temporal unboundedness. But the situation is more subtle than this as time is itself subtle. So, you agree that your statement 'the latest measurements from WMAP indicate a spatially infinite universe with very high certainty' is mistaken?

Comment: Nope, I'm not mistaken. Any mistake here is WMAP's. Experiments at the moment are overwhelmingly in favor of a flat geometry, and flat geometries are spatially infinite under typical topological assumptions.

Comment: @DavidH: Typically manifolds in mathematics are given as unbounded. But there are [Manifolds with boundaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_of_a_manifold#Manifold_with_boundary) and also with corners. Being spatially infinite IS an additional topological assumption and not something that can deduced from local flatness. Are WMAP specifically claiming that the universe is spatially unbounded? Can you point that out on their webpage? If they are then its a spectacular claim

Comment: Perhaps not quite on the level of discovering that the speed of light in a vacuum varies as one recent laboratory claimed, and then eventually retracted. But its very definitely going against a key cosmological claim of GR as you yourself pointed out. I'd expect them to be very cautious in advancing such a claim. Plus I don't see how its empirically possible to measure spatial infinity.

Comment: A circle of radius R has a curvature 1/R. If R is infinite, we can't measure it since all rulers have finite length. But the curvature will still be finite, and if it is zero then the radius is greater than any finite value, i.e., infinity

Comment: Fair enough. Presumably the WMAP experiment relies on measurements of curvature that do not involve R.

Comment: Yup, general relativity takes care of that: curvature ~ gravity ~ density of matter.

Comment: @DavidH: This still goes against the a key cosmological claim of GR. The radius of the the universe being 2cT as you pointed out. How do you explain that?

Comment: 2cT is only just the diameter of the of the part of space in our past light-cone. Think about how the horizon restricts you to seeing only a few square miles of the Earth's at any given location, though the higher you are above the Earth the larger the circular portion of its surface will be in your field of view.

Comment: Ok, I've asked this question in Physics Q&A. It looks like my assumption of the emergence of spacetime at time zero is wrong - but only because its not understood. As some-one put it there - at time zero space is infinite but the distance between any two points is zero. Bizarre.

Comment: "He states that the infinite is not an object or a thing. So it can't be identified with the universe." That is exactly my question: I believe that Hoyle's (and company's) static universe allow for an **actual** Infinity: (quickly grabbed from wikipedia): "The steady state theory asserts that although the universe is expanding, it nevertheless does not change its appearance over time (the perfect cosmological principle); it has no beginning and no end."